# Drag and drop files and folders between Windows 10 and Ubuntu on VMware

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, virtualization, vmware-workstation

I need to drag and drop files between Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04; the last one is installed on VMware workstation 16.0.

I installed the VMware tools; in the settings->options->guest isolation the two boxes "enable drag and drop" and "enable copy and paste" are checked and dimmed. The problem is that I am able only to copy and paste text, but not files and folders.

How can I fix this problem? I tried also to reinstall VMware tools, but the result is the same. Online there are videos like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0krqu_NhR5g&ab_channel=sunguruITChannel01): here the solution is to reinstall VMware tools.

P.S.: I have a shared folder between the two operating systems, but it is uncomfortable for me.

Answer (score 0):

Go to this path, so you can find your dragged files

```
/var/run/vmblock-fuse/blockdir/
```

for view the full path of your current dragged file, just drag the file to terminal window